# I am having trouble understanding if my production rules are context-free grammar or not

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

From my understanding, a context-free grammar (CFG) is any set of production rules that does not contain any $\lambda$-productions and moreover non-terminal symbols cannot *reproduce* themselves. The formal definitons states that CFGs are simply a set of production rules that are one-to-one, one-to-many, or one-to-none which sounds a little ambiguous. All the examples of simple CFGs give the same rules which are pretty much:
$$
\begin{align*}
S &\rightarrow AA \\ A &\rightarrow \alpha\ |\ \beta
\end{align*}
$$
and that makes sense, but my problem is that from these kinds of simple examples I cannot tell if I am actually producing a CFG.

One of the questions for my homework asks:

Find a CFG for the language: $L = \{a^n b^n :$ n is a multiple of 3$\}$

My answer:
$$
G = (\{S,A,B\},\{a,b\},S,P)\\
\begin{align*}
S &\rightarrow A \\
A &\rightarrow aaabbb \\
A &\rightarrow B \\
B &\rightarrow aaaAbbb\\
\end{align*}
$$

But I feel like I am missing something because I cannot tell if this is correct.

Comment: This is a context-free grammar.  The definition of context-free grammar that I remember is that the left-hand side of each production is a single non-terminal.  However, your grammar doesn't produce the language.  You need to add $A\rightarrow\lambda$

Comment: Accoring to the wiki page on context-free grammars, in order to be proper there should be no $\lambda$-productions

Comment: "Proper CFG" is a technical term for a particular kind of CFG. saulsplatz's comment is exactly right for ordinary CFGs. Your language $L$ includes the empty string (because $0$ is a multiple of $3$) and so it can only be defined by a grammar that allows the empty string on the right-hand side of some production (and "proper" CFGs don't support that).

Comment: Oh I see. That was kinda what was throwing me off. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, taking into account the comments, the following CFG will do the job:
$$
\begin{align*}
S &\to \lambda\\
S &\to aaaSbbb
\end{align*}
$$